# How to pass parameter to event object aws lambda functions in nodejs 8.10v

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am working project there we are creating a serverless architecture for handle computation task. How to pass parameters to event object in aws lambda function.

Is there any reference link, if any please suggest.

**index.js - handler function of lambda**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const mysql = require("mysql");
  const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "test_db.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user: "root",
    password: "xxxxxxxx",
    database: "test_db",
    port: 3306
  });

  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    // const { fund_name, returns, aum, rating, expense_ratio } = event.body; // BODY PARAMETER REMAINING
    const randomNumber = () => Math.random()*10+1;
    const fund_name = 'example';
    const returns = randomNumber();
    const aum = randomNumber();
    const rating = randomNumber();
    const expense_ratio = randomNumber();

    if (fund_name && returns && aum && rating && expense_ratio) {
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }

        const query = `INSERT INTO mutual_fund_tb(fund_name, returns, aum, rating, expense_ratio) VALUES ('${fund_name}', '${returns}', '${aum}', '${rating}', '${expense_ratio}')`;
        connection.query(query, (err, results, fields) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }

          if (results.affectedRows === 1) {
            const response = {
              data: {...event.body},
              message: "Data successfully inserted",
              status: "ok"
            };
            callback(null, response);
          } else {
            const response = {
              data: {},
              message: "Data unable to insert into database.",
              status: "failed"
            };
            callback(null, response);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      const response = {
        data: {},
        message: "Invalid arguments passed. Please pass valid arguments",
        status: "failed"
      };
      callback(null, response);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: The answer will depend on what the source event is for the lambda. You'll need to provide a bit more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LukeWaite, I have added index.js handler function of lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you are using API Gateway then on the method execution diagram click on the the integration Response (Integration type Lambda Function) and under that we have `Body mapping template` field where in you can add `application/json` or `txt/xml` and then enter the mapping manually for e.g. in our case we use application/json

`{
    "abc" : $input.params('$def')
}`

So `abc` can be accessed in you lambda function and `def` can be passed on the `url` when calling the API Gateway

As of now you can use **lambda proxy integration** and then you don't need to provide this mapping, and still you will be able to access the parameters
[aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda-build)